# How do I mask a div to its parent dimensions?

Tags: css

I have a rounded rectangle as a background and would like to place another shape on top. The overlaying shape should mask the underlying shape, preferably without any weird coloring at the edges.

I tried to make this work by matching up the shape dimensions, but the `border-radius` property does not align perfectly with the darker background where the rounded edges overlap.

**Imperfect coloring to the left:**

```css
body {
 margin: 100px;
}

#outer-shape {
 height: 25px;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 12.5px;
 background-color: #191932;
}

#inner-shape {
 height: 25px;
 width: 50%;
 border-radius: 12.5px 0 0 12.5px;
 background-color: #fa6400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overlapping Shapes</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="outer-shape">
   <div id="inner-shape"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to have my child div remain a rectangle and then clip the parent div? The point is to hide anything that falls outside the boundaries of the underlying shape.

**Is it possible to clip the rectangle to the parent shape?**

```css
body {
 margin: 100px;
}

#outer-shape {
 height: 25px;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 12.5px;
 background-color: #191932;
}

#inner-shape {
 height: 25px;
 width: 50%;
 opacity: 25%;
 background-color:rgba(250, 100, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overlapping Shapes</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="outer-shape">
   <div id="inner-shape"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Perhaps, I should have mentioned that the point is to convert the design into a progress bar; meaning that I will need to update the width of the overlaying shape (orange). It should be possible to set a width from 0% up to 100%, while still displaying a distinct separation between the two shapes (no gradient transition).

Besides this, I seek to answer my original question: *Is it possible to clip the rectangle to the parent shape?*

If you look closely, shape 1) and shape 2) are slightly different at the edges. The first one has an underlying darker background color, which can be seen by looking at the somewhat rougher edge. The second image is simply the same shape, without any layers beneath. This is really nitpicking, but I cannot avoid seeing the imperfect edge in the first example where the rounding is applied.

Is there a way to keep the underlying darker color and have the smooth rounded edge as seen in the second example?

[image]

Comment: Using `overflow:hidden` to parent?

Comment: @Kenny wont work, leads to the same effect

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why you don't color the parent with two color instead?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The point is to convert the design into a progress bar using JavaScript, so I must be able to update the width of the element from 0% to 100%, while still displaying a distinct separation between the two colors. I do not want a gradient transition from one color to the other, as some of the answers seem to include.

Comment: still a job of gradient where you can easily adjust the width of colors: https://jsfiddle.net/8r4cunmj/1/

Comment: This looks promising! I will accept this answer since you managed to remove the harsh edge and keep the distinct separation in color. Thank you for your solution :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I noticed that I cannot accept your comment as the answer to my question. Could you perhaps post an official answer so that I can mark it as accepted? Thank you again for the creative solution :)

Comment: your question was closed, so I cannot add an answer. I voted to reopened it. Once it get reopened I will post my asnwer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple background for this where you can easily control the size using `background-size`

```css
.outer-shape {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fa6400, #fa6400) left/50% 100% no-repeat, 
    #191932;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-shape"></div>
<div class="outer-shape" style="background-size:20% 100%"></div>
<div class="outer-shape" style="background-size:60% 100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent element

```css
body {
 margin: 100px;
}

#outer-shape {
 height: 25px;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 12.5px;
 background-color: #191932;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#inner-shape {
 height: 25px;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: #fa6400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overlapping Shapes</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="outer-shape">
   <div id="inner-shape"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The imperfection is still visible in your solution :(

Answer (score -1):

`overflow:hidden` on the parent will lead to the same imperfect coloring.
But you can use:

body {
    margin: 100px;
}

```
#outer-shape {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 12.5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fa6400 50%, #191932 50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fmvsk8g9/5/

Side by Side
https://jsfiddle.net/8nzL17mp/1/

Comment: I didn't understand... how is margin on `body` will have impact on these div?

Comment: margin does not have impact. its just for aligning the element. The mainly difference is that in this solution there is no nested element. Watch implementations side by side: https://jsfiddle.net/8nzL17mp/1/

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that I will need to update the width of the element. Your solution only works if I want the split to be in the very center of the rounded rectangle. As an example, your solution does not work with `background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fa6400 40%, #191932 60%);`. The color separation now becomes a gradient, which is something I wish to avoid.

Comment: @MajesticPixel to avoid the gradient both numbers have to be the same.   background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fa6400 30%, #191932 30%);